# Finding ratios between two triangles (one inscribed in a semicircle)

Tags: geometry, triangles, circles

[image]

I've been working on part 2 of this problem for a while (I managed to finish part 1 (prove that $\angle ARP \simeq \angle QRB$ )) and I just can't seem to find a way to start calculating the ratios of $\triangle QRB$ and $\triangle AQP$. I would really appreciate any help on the problem - I'm really stuck!

Thanks.

Comment: If $O$ is at $(0,0)$ and $A$ at $(-1,0)$ and $B$ at $(1,0)$ then you may be able to show $P$ is at $(0,1)$ and for part (2) $R$ at $(2,0)$ and then you can find the location of $Q$ in which case finding the areas and their ratio is not hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Prove that $\triangle AEC$ 
is similar to $\triangle BDE$.

These triangles are similar, since they share the angle $AEC$
and $\angle CAE=\angle EBD=45^\circ$, since

\begin{align} 
\angle DBA&=90^\circ
,\quad 
\angle ABC=\tfrac12\angle AOC=45^\circ
,\\
\angle EBD&=180^\circ-\angle DBA-\angle ABC=45^\circ
.
\end{align}

It follows that $\angle ECA=\angle BDE$
and hence, triangles $ABC$ and $BDE$ are also similar.

When $|DE|=|OD|=R$ we have $R_{ABC}=R$ as a radius of the circumscribed circle of  $\triangle ABC$,
and by the sine rule the circumradius of $\triangle BDE$ is found as

\begin{align}
R_{BDE}&=\frac{|DE|}{2\sin\angle EBD}
=\frac{R}{2\sin 45^\circ}
=\tfrac{\sqrt2}2\,R
,\\
\end{align}

Hence, the ratio of the areas of 
$\triangle ABC$
and
$\triangle BDE$ is
\begin{align}
\frac{S_{ABC}}{S_{BDE}}
&=
\frac{R_{ABC}^2}{R_{BDE}^2}
=\frac{R^2}{(\tfrac{\sqrt2}2\,R)^2}
=2
.
\end{align}

Comment: I understand until when you have calculated that $\sqrt{2} R/2$ is $R_{BDE}$ but how are you able to conclude that the area of the triangle is equivalent to each $R^2$?

Comment: @mathinjpm:
A well-known formula for the area
$S_{ABC}=2R^2\sin\alpha\sin\beta\sin\gamma$,
which can be easily derived from the sine rule
and, foor example, more known $S=\tfrac12 ab\sin\gamma$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I really appreciate it.